# Is there a way to work out the final mean±sd from the baseline mean±sd and change in mean±sd?

Tags: mean

I'm performing a meta analysis on PSA (prostate specific antigen) values and comparing a placebo group with a treatment group. In one paper I have the mean baseline PSA values±SD and the mean absolute change in PSA±SD and I need to find the final mean PSA value and standard deviation from this.
For example, the baseline mean±SD is 5.63±4.18 and the change in mean is - 0.66±2.56, how do I find the final mean±SD from this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The first thing you might try is to contact the authors of the original paper and see if they provide the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the follow-up mean, providing the baseline and change data is on the same number of people (e.g. it's not the case that the baseline was on 25 people with 5 lost to follow-up and only 20 included in the change data). This would be by addition (i.e. 5.63 + (-0.66) = 4.97).

For the SD, it's a little more complicated. The variance (which you can square root to get the SD) of a change depends on the baseline variance (which is just the SD squared), the follow-up variance, and their covariance. The last of these can be obtained from their SDs and the correlation between them. If you knew the correlation between baseline and follow-up values, you could calculate the follow-up SD with the other information you have. However, without that piece of information, you have one equation with two unknowns here and so your options would be to a) "guess" what sort of correlation is reasonable, b) find another article and use their correlation if you feel it is reasonable for this situation, or c) contact the authors. The last of these is the option I would recommend.